# Symfony Inject Token storage in form type

Tags: symfony

I need to know the user connected in a form event listener. So I have injected the **token storage** in my **formType** class and have declare the service. But it does not seems to work.

Did I do something wrong?

```
class AlertType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Votre adresse email'));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    }

    public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        dump($user);
        die;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FM\MailAlertBundle\Entity\Alert',
        ));
    }
}
```

service declaration:

```
 services:
        fm.mail_alert.form.alert_type:
            class: FM\MailAlertBundle\Form\AlertType
            arguments:
                - '@security.token_storage'
            tags:
                - { name: form.type }
```

Error message:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   FM\MailAlertBundle\Form\AlertType::__construct() must implement
>   interface
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface,
>   none given

My purpose is to disable the field email if a user is connected.

Comment: how do you use it?

Comment: My purpose is to disable the field email if a user is connected. @Matteo

Comment: Sorry, Are you using it as example: `$form = $this->createForm(AlertType::class, $alert);` ?

Comment: Yes, but I can not give the token storage to the formType as an argument, I prefer to use DI, because this form is use multiple time in the project. @Matteo

Comment: Hi you shouldn't pass argument by yourself: the DI do it for you....

Comment: Just to confirm your code is never doing new AlertType()?  Are you sure the services file is being loaded and that you have the correct AlertType class name?  Does bin/console debug:container show your AlertType service?

Comment: @Cerad Yes my code is doing `new AlertType()` multiple time. The service is loaded and I see my service in the debug container.

Comment: new AlertType does not use the container.  Hence the problem.  And starting with 2.8, you can no longer pass a type instance.  You have to use the type class name which in turn will pull from the container.

Answer (score 0):

Cool. I use symfony 2.8 so I had to change `new AlertType` by `AlertType::class` in my controller and it worked ;)