# Add custom form type only when user is not authorized

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have created a custom form type - `RecaptchaType`. I added it into many forms using `$builder->add('recaptcha', RecaptchaType::class)`. For view I have created a macro, so in twig I render it as follows `{{ forms.recaptcha(form.recaptcha) }}`.

But now I want to display recaptcha only for users who are not logged in. In twig macro I can simple add if condition. But how can I achieve not adding (or removing) recaptcha input in form type if I want to edit only RecaptchaType and don't want to touch form types, which are using this.

I had two ideas, but neither of them did work.

- In RecaptchaType use function buildForm and do `$builder->remove('recaptcha')` when condition is met (user is logged in)
- Pass option 'render' to `$resolver->setDefaults()`, access it in form and depend on value do `->add` or not. But I can't access the value.

How would you do that? I can add code example if needed.

Comment: How do you check inside the Recaptcha Form Type if the user is logged in?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why both ideas (reasonable for me) didn't work for you?

Comment: Greg: I can inject `security.token_storage` into it.

Comment: yceruto: `->remove('recaptcha')` must be called in the concrete form type, not in `RecaptchaType`. So for example if I use `RecaptchaType` in ArticleType and I want to show recaptcha only for non-authorized user I must do this `->remove` logic in `ArticleType`. But the point is to do it without editing `ArticleType`, because I want this logic in `RecaptchaType`.

And second idea did non work, because if I add option in `RecaptchaType` and dump all options in `ArticleType` it is simply not in there. Probably options of used types are not bubbling into parent form type.

Comment: Have you checked this question on so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722693/symfony-inject-token-storage-in-form-type. Seems that OP did something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;** To remove a form type conditionally encapsulating this logic within itself, you can do the follows:

`RecaptchaType`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        if ($this->isAuthenticated()) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->getParent()->remove($form->getName());
        }
    });
}
```

Now, if you are customizing the form theme make sure to check the existence of the field before render it:

```
{% if form.recaptcha is defined %}
    {{ forms.recaptcha(form.recaptcha) }}
{% endif %}
```

It should work as long as your `RecaptchaType` is embedded into another form.